# Transliterate arabic characters into english - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, character

I want to convert arabic characters into english characters.

I want to convert the tile of post in wordpress and transliterate into english characters.
and store it in a variable like $entitle.

how can i do it?

Can please someone help?

```
if ($this->registry->options['invetag_seotopic_ahmed_php'] AND $zwr_ahmedPHP == "show") {

    $en = str_split('{}DFL:"ZCV<>`qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;\'zxcvnm,./~QWERYIOPASHJKXNM?');

    $ar = str_split('<>][/:"~}{,.ذضصثقفغعهخحجدشسيبلاتنمكطئءؤرىةوزظًٌَُّإ÷×؛ٍِأـ،ْآ’؟');

    for ($ahmedPHP = 0; $ahmedPHP < count($seotopic_thread); $ahmedPHP++) {

        $inv_tmp = str_replace($ar, $en, $seotopic_thread[$ahmedPHP]);

        $inv_ar_tmp [] = str_replace(array('لا', 'لآ', 'لأ', 'لإ', '‘'), array('b', 'B', 'G', 'T', 'U'), $inv_tmp);
    }

    if (is_array($inv_ar_tmp)) {

        $invtag = implode(" ", $inv_ar_tmp);
        $invtag = '<hr size="1" style="color:#D1D1E1; background-color:#D1D1E1" />' . "<p class=\"alt2\" dir=\"ltr\" style=\"margin: 1px auto;  padding: 6px;border: 1px inset; width: 640px;height: 34px;text-align: left;overflow: auto\">" . $invtag . "</p>\n";
        $post[message] = $post[message] . $invtag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have no idea what that code is supposed to do. Can you try to clarify what your problem is?

Comment: thx for answer , all i need is convert page title with php to english , like this اسم الصفحة to > hsl hgwtpm so all char will convert and outs char to variable like $entitle to use in page for wordpress

Comment: more details is any arabic char like أ to h

Comment: Why don't you make a plugin to keep both versions and use the English version when needed it would save you a lot of resource than converting it on the fly all the time.

Comment: plugin need alot of work and need it just for page title to get it in variable and add it on some pages to got more seo , can same one help me to add it to my wordpress!! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using str_split fro spliting the arabic multi byte charactors.
you need to use a multibyte function.

eg:

```
function multibyte_str_split($string) {
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    while ($strlen) {
        $array[] = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
        $string = mb_substr($string, 1, $strlen, "UTF-8");
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    }
    return $array;
}


$arb = <<<EOD
            <>][/:"~}{,.ذضصثقفغعهخحجدشسيبلاتنمكطئءؤرىةوزظًٌَُّإ÷×؛ٍِأـ،ْآ’؟
EOD;

$ar = multibye_str_split($arb);
```

EDIT: 
put this function in the 'functions.php' file in your theme.

```
function arb2en_title($post=0)
{
  $text = get_the_title($post);


$arb_en_map=array ( 
'\\xd8\\xa1' => '\'', '\\xd8\\xa2' => '|', '\\xd8\\xa3' => '>',
'\\xd8\\xa4' => '&', '\\xd8\\xa5' => '<', '\\xd8\\xa6' => '}',
'\\xd8\\xa7' => 'A', '\\xd8\\xa8' => 'b', '\\xd8\\xa9' => 'p',
'\\xd8\\xaa' => 't', '\\xd8\\xab' => 'v', '\\xd8\\xac' => 'j',
'\\xd8\\xad' => 'H', '\\xd8\\xae' => 'x', '\\xd8\\xaf' => 'd',
'\\xd8\\xb0' => '*', '\\xd8\\xb1' => 'r', '\\xd8\\xb2' => 'z',
'\\xd8\\xb3' => 's', '\\xd8\\xb4' => '$', '\\xd8\\xb5' => 'S',
'\\xd8\\xb6' => 'D', '\\xd8\\xb7' => 'T', '\\xd8\\xb8' => 'Z',
'\\xd8\\xb9' => 'E', '\\xd8\\xba' => 'g', '\\xd9\\x80' => '_',
'\\xd9\\x81' => 'f', '\\xd9\\x82' => 'q', '\\xd9\\x83' => 'k',
'\\xd9\\x84' => 'l', '\\xd9\\x85' => 'm', '\\xd9\\x86' => 'n',
'\\xd9\\x87' => 'h', '\\xd9\\x88' => 'w', '\\xd9\\x89' => 'Y',
'\\xd9\\x8a' => 'y', '\\xd9\\x8b' => 'F', '\\xd9\\x8c' => 'N',
'\\xd9\\x8d' => 'K', '\\xd9\\x8e' => 'a', '\\xd9\\x8f' => 'u',
'\\xd9\\x90' => 'i', '\\xd9\\x91' => '~', '\\xd9\\x92' => 'o',
'\\xd9\\xb0' => '`', '\\xd9\\xb1' => '{', 
        );

foreach($arb_en_map as $key=>$value)
{
    $text=preg_replace("/$key/",$value,$text);
}
return  htmlentities($text);

}
```

in your theme, you can get the title in english by calling the 
 arb2en_title() function.

eg:

```
echo arb2en_title();
```

Note: i have used the buckwalter transliteration chart.

http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/morph/buckwalter.html

EDIT::

for arbic key board mapping like in this link: 
http://elfnoon.com/demo/maps.html

replace the arb_en_map array with this:

```
$arb_en_map=array(
            'د'=>']',
           'ج'=>'[',
           'ح'=>'p',
           'خ'=>'o',
           'ه'=>'i',
           'ع'=>'u',
           'غ'=>'y',
           'ف'=>'t',
           'ق'=>'r',
           'ث'=>'e',
           'ص'=>'w',
           'ض'=>'q',
           'ش'=>'a',
           'س'=>'s',
           'ي'=>'d',
           'ب'=>'f',
           'ل'=>'g',
           'ا'=>'h',
           'ت'=>'j',
           'ن'=>'k',
           'م'=>'l',
           'ك'=>';',
           'ط'=>'\'',
           'ظ'=>'/',
           'ز'=>'.',
           'و'=>',',
           'ة'=>'m',
           'ى'=>'n',
           'ل'=>'b',
           'ر'=>'v',
           'ؤ'=>'c',
           'ء'=>'x',
           'ئ'=>'z',
           'إ'=>'Y',
           'لإ'=>'T',
           'لأ'=>'G',
           'أ'=>'H',
           'لآ'=>'B',
           'آ'=>'N'
);
```

or you can use the hex mapping array, both are same:

```
$arb_en_map=array ( 
 '\\xd8\\xaf' => ']', '\\xd8\\xac' => '[', '\\xd8\\xad' => 'p',
 '\\xd8\\xae' => 'o', '\\xd9\\x87' => 'i', '\\xd8\\xb9' => 'u',
 '\\xd8\\xba' => 'y', '\\xd9\\x81' => 't', '\\xd9\\x82' => 'r',
 '\\xd8\\xab' => 'e', '\\xd8\\xb5' => 'w', '\\xd8\\xb6' => 'q',
 '\\xd8\\xb4' => 'a', '\\xd8\\xb3' => 's', '\\xd9\\x8a' => 'd',
 '\\xd8\\xa8' => 'f', '\\xd9\\x84' => 'B', '\\xd8\\xa7' => 'h',
 '\\xd8\\xaa' => 'j', '\\xd9\\x86' => 'k', '\\xd9\\x85' => 'l',
 '\\xd9\\x83' => ';', '\\xd8\\xb7' => '\'', '\\xd8\\xb8' => '/',
 '\\xd8\\xb2' => '.', '\\xd9\\x88' => ',', '\\xd8\\xa9' => 'm', 
 '\\xd9\\x89' => 'n', '\\xd8\\xb1' => 'v', '\\xd8\\xa4' => 'c', 
 '\\xd8\\xa1' => 'x', '\\xd8\\xa6' => 'z', '\\xd8\\xa5' => 'Y',
 '\\xd8\\xa3' => 'H', '\\xd8\\xa2' => 'N',
 );
```

Comment: thx but not know how to get page title and add it to new variable in wordpress , can you show me??

Comment: $post[message] = $post[message] . $invtag; what is this?

Comment: $post[message] for show post with new adds and next $post[message] is with $invtag to add both in $post[message]

Comment: $seotopic_thread has the page title that you want to add in all the pages? and you want to add the the new element $invtag in all the posts or just the pages?

Comment: or you want to get the current page's title and conver it into arabic and add it to the page as an tag?

Comment: i use tag but it arabic so i want english char to get high seo search .. need out english char to use it with variable and add it in pages , hope you help me >> all page are arabic

Comment: any hope to do that?!!

Comment: after edit have erorr with line $arb_to_en_title=str_replace(array('لا', 'لآ', 'لأ', 'لإ', '''), array('b', 'B', 'G', 'T', 'U'),$arb_to_en_title); -=-=-=-= full error in browser >> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in wp-content\themes\new\page.php on line 31

Comment: make sure you are copy pasting the code properly. you are getting the error cos ` (back tick) is getting coverted to ' (single qoute) when you are copy pasting str_replace(array('لا', 'لآ', 'لأ', 'لإ', '''),.  anyway, this is not the right way to transliterate the text, you shoudl check out existing plugins.

Comment: sorry no any plugin do that :( can you help me!!

Comment: please help no any plugin help to change arabic char to english

Comment: thx but the code convert char like frist character in arabic is ا and convert to A , but i need convert character like ا to h like in the keyboard , that help in search engine like who type hpl] search engine  will see it is احمد not like now it see ahmed more explain if my page is التصميم and need to convert like i want it will be hgjwldl so char ا = h , ل = g , ت = j , ص = w , م = l , ي = d , م = l <<< like that and another special char like 'لا','لآ','لأ','لإ','‘' will be 'b','B','G','T','U' hope get the idea and help me , and i forget thanks to you for helping me with new idea :)

Comment: for that, you will need to put a complete list of of arabic to english character mapping ie: ا = h , ل = g , ت = j , ص = w , م = l , ي = d , م = l  for all the arabic characters.  refer this link:http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/morph/buckwalter.html. give me  a link or the list of characters i can help you with the coding.

Comment: this can help http://elfnoon.com/demo/maps.html with arabic char and keyboard and same char need press shift with it but know how array for that , thx again bro

Comment: thx alot bro i edit same char to make it good and now is good , but with use plguin for seo plugin repleace the title with title in wp-admin , i will work to get the variable of seo page name , thx alot bro